# submit two forms with a single button jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have two forms in one page, and I wanted to submit both with one submit button. I have  tried other solutions in Stackoverflow but couldn't get it. It doesn't redirect to demo.php. Below my code.

### HTML

```
<form id="form1" class="multiple-choice">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" class="input-checkboxitem">
    <label for="check1">Materials</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" class="input-checkboxitem">
    <label for="check2">Exam Method</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check3" class="input-checkboxitem">
    <label for="check3">Learning Method</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="check4" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check4" class="input-checkboxitem">
    <label for="check4">Evaluation</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="check5" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check5" class="input-checkboxitem">
    <label for="check5">User Friendliness</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="check6" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check6" class="input- checkboxitem">
    <label for="check6">None</label>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio4" class="css-label radGroup2">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio5" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="radio5" class="css-label radGroup2">No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio6" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="radio6" class="css-label radGroup2">May be</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
<div class="form_result"></div>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('form input[type ="radio"], input[type ="checkbox"]' ).click(function(){          
            $.ajax({ type:'POST', url:'demo.php', data:$('#form1, #form2).serialize(),      success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $('body').find('.form_result').html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });     
    });
```

Comment: You can use jquery submit function ..

$("#firstformId").submit();
$("#secondformId").submit();

Comment: add method="POST" for both the forms. By default it will be a GET call

Comment: Your JavaScript is not valid. `data:$('#form1, #form2).serialize()` is missing a single quote in the selector...

Comment: @Udaysri i tried but doesn't work

Comment: @saurabhsinha is it necessary to write post when i defined that in ajax.

Comment: @skeryl i corrected it but nothing change

Comment: It looks like your JavaScript is functioning as expected. Check out this JSFiddle where I have removed the interaction with your PHP script: http://jsfiddle.net/SLNt4/5/
I would take a look at how the request is handled by your PHP and what is being returned in the response.

Comment: there is just a echo in php page <?php echo 'sth'; ?>. I just wanted to redirect to this url when i click the submit button, but there is no response when i click the submit button.